# Getting Json data in the Angularjs Scope

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

This is my first attempt at using Angularjs framework. I am trying to follow this example: http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/11/

I am successfully able to get the data in the Json format and it works fine. 
json data:

```
[{"Activity_Matrix_ID":"163","Activity_ID":"131","Activity_Date":"2062-02-16","Activity_Category":"Maintanence","Activity_Project":"All Projects","Activity_Description":"Json data ","Activity_Hours":"2"},{"Activity_Matrix_ID":"161","Activity_ID":"129","Activity_Date":"2044-02-25","Activity_Category":"Tech Support","Activity_Project":"All Projects","Activity_Description":"Dummy dummy ","Activity_Hours":""}]
```

So basically, I want to load the data in $scope.items. I am not sure if it is the good method. I can visit the url and the data looks fine.  I am stuck at getting the json correctly from the URL to the angular scope.

I tried following

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sortingOrder = 'Activity_Projects';
    </script>

<script>
function ctrlRead($scope, $filter) {

         $scope.myData = function(item, event) {

          var responsePromise = $http.get({method: 'GET', url: 'https://url_root_same_domain/timesheet/timesheet_info_table_json.php'}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

              $scope.items = data; 
              console.log(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              alert("No data");
            });
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: Use Angular's $http.get() to load data.  You've provided a lot of code, so it is difficult to sort through.  Can you put together a simple sample demonstrating your problem?

Comment: Hi Jeffry, I am having trouble with $http.get() method. Now the code is edited to show the problematic area. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var responsePromise = $http.get('https://url_root_same_domain/timesheet/timesheet_info_table_json.php').success(...rest of your code here
```

The [$http.get()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) function's first argument is a URL; not an object; and the method of a get call is already get, so you shouldn't have to do any other changes.

Comment: I am getting this error in the console:  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". I guess the json is still not able to load and it is trying to parse "undefined".

Comment: function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http)
{
    
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'https://root_url/timesheet/timesheet_info_table_json.php'}).success(function(data)
{
$scope.items = data; // response data 
console.log(data);
});
}
Do you think this syntax is correct? I am pretty sure that I am able to access the json url. I tried putting the php code which retrieves the json data directly into $scope.data and it works fine.

Comment: The syntax looks right to me; however I usually use the helper functions, and don't know the 'native' syntax off the top of my head

Comment: I was finally able to get the Json data in the console using the URL but it still does not display all the data in the table. I had to inject $http in ctrlRead.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter','$http']; and I had to use JSON.stringify on the returned data.Thanks for the comments and response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I should have noticed you weren't injecting $http into the controller.  My bad!

Comment: I am still not getting the data into the table. Everything looks fine to me. Any ideas? I got the JSON response and it shows as [object] [object]. DO I have to loop over the individual elements of the JSON?Thank you